# Workflow foundation locale setting different from instantiated thread

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, workflow-foundation-4

I am hosting a few workflows inside a MVC project.

In the web.config, I set the CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture to en-AU while the server is en (or was it en-US, doesn't matter).

Anyway, the MVC site runs in Aus locale fine, but workflow foundation is in the original locale (en-US).

Setting it when workflow starts resolves the problem, but it seems more like a hack than a solution.

So, how do I set the locale of the workflow thread?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you host the workflow? As a service under IIS, using AppFabric, using WokrlfowApplication?

Comment: I am hosting it inside a MVC runtime. It's using WorkflowApplication class to start it.